# Cannot create Sql Server 2008R2 Service-based database in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012

I have Visual Studio Express 2013 and SQL Server 2008R2 installed on my laptop.

In Visual Studio when I add a Service-based Database to my project i.e. Right Click > Add > New Item > Service-base Database it creates SQL Service Database .mdf version 11.00.3000 which is SQL Service 2012 SP1

Is there anyway to specify the target database version when creating it through Visual Studio? I've had various permissions/configuration issues when creating them through Sql Server Management Studio so due to sheer laziness of having to update settings each time would like to avoid it if possible

Comment: I suspect you're creating a "Local DB" database. Try connecting to the server in server manager, opening SQL Server Object Explorer and creating from there.

Comment: Yeah that's the idea, was hoping to avoid server manager if possible but would like to specify the Local DB version so I can use SSMS if I wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

How is the creation of service based database by visual studio 2013 shall be set up tables and link tables created. How is the creation of service based database by visual studio 2013 shall be set up tables and link tables created